# Getting Memory waning in UIImage?(data:)

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting an Image as `Data` from server.To show it I am using `UIImage?(data:)` to show it.For a specific image application is getting crash because of memory pressure. What could be the reason, how to fix it.

```
    if let imgData = Utils.fetchDataFromDocumentDirectory(imageName:"test.jpg"){
        attachmentImgView.image = UIImage(data:imgData)
    }
```

Comment: Are you download image from server?

Comment: How big is the image?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38152734/341994

Answer (score 0):

How big is the Image? and are you downloading only 1 image or an array?

This might be caused from the size of the image you are trying to download.

My advice if you are trying to show an image, only giving it the url like so:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/w5rkSIj.jpg")
let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)

if let imageData = data {
    let image = UIImage(data: data)
}
```

even better you can try to use AsyncImageView 3rd party library where you give it the url of the image and it shows it asynchronously without delays in the app.

Hope this helps!

Comment: size of image is not too much. That is of only 4 mb size.I have saved that image in my document directory.